# Sandbox Wordpress linked to Live Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site that needs a major overhaul... Made a separate domain for a testing environment. Changed all settings I can think of, edited the database when I exported, defined the new url and home in the wp-config file...

Yet somehow i'm getting linked to the old site.
In other words, i'm on newsite.com but it's really pulling from oldsite.com.

So newsite.com/wp-admin is really oldsite.com/wp-admin ... Any changes I make are reflected on the old site, not the new.

I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: Check .htaccess url-rewrite rules

Comment: All the links seem to be working properly... But when I modify any plugin settings it ACTUALLY does it on the old site

Comment: It sounds like you are still using the database from the old site, which is where plugin settings are saved. How do you have the database setup on the new site?

Comment: I copied the database, opened in notepad, did a find and replace for oldurl.com to newurl.com... Have done searches on my server in the new directory for the old name, it isn't there... Config is linked to new db and site

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you define both WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://newsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://newsite.com');
```

Then add update the siteurl and home options by adding this to the functions.php file in your theme:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://newsite.com');
update_option('home','http://newsite.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the WP_HOME and WP_SITE settings dynamically to match the current domain:

In your wp-config.php change the lines to read:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```